# HPA ScalingLimited=True TooFewReplicas

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

That is my HPA. I want to start the deployment with default replicas=3

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: backend-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: backend

  minReplicas: 3
  maxReplicas: 20

  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: AverageValue
          averageValue: 500Mi
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 70

  behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
      policies:
        - type: Pods
          value: 1
          periodSeconds: 100

    scaleUp:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 60
      policies:
        - type: Pods
          value: 1
          periodSeconds: 30
        - type: Percent
          value: 10
          periodSeconds: 60
      selectPolicy: Max
```

But it always says:
**ScalingLimited  True    TooFewReplicas    the desired replica count is less than the minimum replica count** and I can't understand why.

```bash
➜ kg hpa
NAME                  REFERENCE                    TARGETS                       MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
prod-backend-hpa-v1   Deployment/prod-backend-v1   145881770666m/500Mi, 2%/70%   3         20        3          7m16s


➜ kd hpa
Name:                                                  prod-backend-hpa-v1
Namespace:                                             prod
Labels:                                                argocd.argoproj.io/instance=backend-prod
Annotations:                                           <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                     Thu, 02 Jun 2022 19:34:30 -0500
Reference:                                             Deployment/prod-backend-v1
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods:                             145596416 / 500Mi
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  1% (3m) / 70%
Min replicas:                                          3
Max replicas:                                          20
Behavior:
  Scale Up:
    Stabilization Window: 60 seconds
    Select Policy: Max
    Policies:
      - Type: Pods     Value: 1   Period: 30 seconds
      - Type: Percent  Value: 10  Period: 60 seconds
  Scale Down:
    Stabilization Window: 300 seconds
    Select Policy: Max
    Policies:
      - Type: Pods  Value: 1  Period: 100 seconds
Deployment pods:    3 current / 3 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason            Message
  ----            ------  ------            -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale  recommended size matches current size
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound  the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from memory resource
  ScalingLimited  True    TooFewReplicas    the desired replica count is less than the minimum replica count
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age    From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----   ----                       -------
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  9m22s  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 3; reason: Current number of replicas below Spec.MinReplicas



➜ kgpo  
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
prod-backend-v1-8dd687999-54mzp   1/1     Running   0          58m
prod-backend-v1-8dd687999-nn7c2   1/1     Running   0          2d17h
prod-backend-v1-8dd687999-rcxsw   1/1     Running   0          2d17h

➜ kg rs 
NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
prod-backend-v1-566b9c8856   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-578d699c45   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-64859b74c9   0         0         0       2d18h
prod-backend-v1-6498b4b45c   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-656cccdc4b   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-66cc5cf44    0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-698c7ddc7d   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-6bdbc77f5d   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-7486c95664   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-774cdbdcdc   0         0         0       2d19h
prod-backend-v1-8dd687999    3         3         3       2d17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A horizontal pod autoscaler, defined by a **HorizontalPodAutoscaler** object, specifies how the system should automatically increase or decrease the scale of a replication controller or deployment configuration, based on metrics collected from the pods that belong to that replication controller or deployment configuration.

**ScalingLimited** indicates that autoscaling is not allowed because a maximum or minimum replica count was reached.

1. A **True** condition indicates that you need to raise or lower the minimum or maximum replica count in order to scale.
2. A **False** condition indicates that the requested scaling is allowed.

As per your use case the ScalingLimited shows status as **“True”** with message “desired replica count is less than the minimum replica count”. So, as a workaround you can increase minReplicas or set scaleDown policy with large periodSeconds to increase stabilization periods.

Refer [Pod Autoscaling](https://docs.okd.io/3.7/dev_guide/pod_autoscaling.html#creating-a-hpa) for more information.